# NSArray loop issue

Tags: objective-c, c, for-loop, nsarray

I"ve got a problem in a for loop
I'm putting a NSArray into a tableview and I want the last object to be in the first cell, 
but it only works with the first object.

this works:

```
for(int i = 0; i < messages.count ; i++)
    {
    }
```

but this doesn't:

```
 for(int i = messages.count; i > 0; i--)
    {
    }
```

and the error message is:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 203 beyond bounds [0 .. 202]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x32bd33e7 0x3a8c4963 0x32b1eef9 0x891d3 0x34a01579 0x34a561f7 0x34a5613d 0x34a56021 0x34a55f4d 0x34a55699 0x34a55581 0x34a26561 0x349e58c7 0x34791513 0x347910b5 0x34791fd9 0x347919c3 0x347917d5 0x349eb93f 0x32ba8941 0x32ba6c39 0x32ba6f93 0x32b1a23d 0x32b1a0c9 0x366f833b 0x34a362b9 0x8549d 0x3acf1b20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Comment: for(int i = messages.count - 1; i >= 0; i--) - numeration starts with zero in arrays

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to start the loop at the message count -1 so like this:

```
for (int i = messages.count - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
{
   ...
}
```

Since `messages.count` will give the total number of elements held within the messages object. The greatest element index in the array will be the `messages.count - 1` since the array indices start at 0.

Comment: Why this answer down voted? one should wait it might be a typo error but concept is correct

Answer (score 1):

`for(int i = 0; i < messages.count ; i++)` loops from `0` up to `messages.count-1` (it stops when `i == messages.count`).

`for(int i = messages.count; i > 0; i--)` loops from `messages.count` down to `1`, an entirely different set of indices.

Write

```
for(int i=messages.count-1; i>=0; i--)
```

instead, or [use this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1642028/1204143):

```
int i = messages.count;
while(i --> 0) {
    ...
}
```

or just use `reverseObjectEnumerator`:

```
for(id element in [messages reverseObjectEnumerator]) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Half-open intervals. There's **no object** at `[array objectAtIndex:array.count]`. If, for example, your array contains 5 objects, then there are objects at indices 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Also, in the second case, the counter needs to go until `0`, else you don't take the first object (the one at index 0) into consideration (again: the closed part of the half-open interval is at 0, the open one is at `array.count`).

All in all: change the second loop to

```
for (int i = messages.count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

and it will work fine.